# When to use with clause in sql

Tags: sql-server

Can Anybody tell me when to use with clause.

Comment: When you read the documentation, what did you see there?   Anything specific that confused you?  Could you provide quotes showing what you understand and what you did not understand?  This question -- as asked -- is vague.  Can you make it more specific?

Answer (score 4):

The `WITH` keyword is used to create a temporary named result set. These are called [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).

A very basic, self-explanatory example:

```
WITH Administrators (Name, Surname)
AS
(
    SELECT Name, Surname FROM Users WHERE AccessRights = 'Admin'
)
SELECT * FROM Administrators
```

---

For further reading and more examples, I suggest starting out with the following MSDN article:

- [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx) by John Papa

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you sometimes need the WITH clause to force a query to use an Index. This is often a necessity in spatial queries that can reduce query time from 1 minute to a few seconds.

```
select * from MyTable with(index(MySpatialIndex)) where...
```